# Forward declaration of a class nested in in a class template, is it legal?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Is this code legal under `C++14/17`?

```
template <class T1, class T2 >
class Foo
{
public:
    class sentry;
};

template <class T1,class T2 = int>
class Foo<T1,T2>::sentry
{
public:
    ~sentry() { }
};
```

It compiles with *GCC 4.9.3* but fails with *GCC 5.3*. 
**[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/S-pH6R)**

How can I fix this for *GCC 5.3*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ill-formed according to [[temp.param]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.param#9) (emphasis mine):

> A default template-argument is a template-argument ([temp.arg])
>   specified after = in a template-parameter. A default template-argument
>   may be specified for any kind of template-parameter (type, non-type,
>   template) that is not a template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]). A
>   default template-argument may be specified in a template declaration.
>   **A default template-argument shall not be specified in the
>   template-parameter-lists of the definition of a member of a class
>   template that appears outside of the member's class.** A default
>   template-argument shall not be specified in a friend class template
>   declaration. If a friend function template declaration specifies a
>   default template-argument, that declaration shall be a definition and
>   shall be the only declaration of the function template in the
>   translation unit.

`sentry` is [a member class](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.mem.class) of `Foo`. You defined it outside the class, and so it may not specify a default argument for the parameters of `Foo`. As a general rule of thumb, default arguments should appear only on the primary template declaration.

This rule of thumb is also how your code may be [fixed](https://godbolt.org/z/G_lk4r):

```
template <class T1, class T2 = int>
class Foo
{
public:
    class sentry;
};

template <class T1,class T2>
class Foo<T1,T2>::sentry
{
public:
    ~sentry() { }
};
```

Comment: I was wondering, whether the `sentry` class(OP's case); will come under the case of specialization!... Hmmm looks like tricky basics..

Comment: @JeJo - Not sure I follow you. The paragraph I quoted speak only of out-of-class definitions, no need to consider it a specialization (even though partial specializations don't allow default template argument either).